# Problem with multiple admin accounts and file ownership

Tags: greeter, user

A while ago I was messing around with my elementary OS setup and ended up crashing my main admin account.
I'm not sure exactly what I did but essentially every time I would try to login, I would get stuck in a login loop.  It would halfway log in and then crash and shoot me back to the login screen.
I stopped using elementary OS for a while because of this and went back to my main OS ubuntuMATE.
Today I realized well, one: I really like the look and feel of elementary OS and two: that I could just create a  new account through terminal and add it to the sudo group, successfully creating a new admin account.
It's great I can do everything I need from this account except edit any of the files found in my elementary OS file system as they are all belonging to my main admin account.
How can I go about transferring ownership of all these files to the new admin account and/or delete the old admin account?
Would in deleting the former admin account automatically transfer said files?
How do I solve this?
Thank you for the help in advance.

ZeDD

Comment: very simple `sudo adduser fopedals sudo`

Comment: silly me, useless question I have asked, :)

Comment: Do you have any idea how I should go about fixing this?

Comment: Add new admin account to old admin __group__,

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that.

Comment: what is your old admin account?

Comment: I believe the name of the account is just "fo"

Comment: Suppose if `fo` is name of group: `sudo adduser fopedals fo` then logout and login.

Comment: I've tried this a few times.  It seems I have added fopedals to the group fo, however that doesn't seem to allow me to write to files or at least save files I've written to.

Answer (score 1):

Here the goal is to allow `new admin` to access files whose permissions and ownership  are under `old admin`.

In such cases you can do following:

- change the file ownership or

  ```
  chown user:group filename
  ```
- Add `new admin` to group `old admin`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite quick with some commands.
First you need the uid of your "old admin" and "new admin" account:

`$ id -u old-admin`

`$ id -u new-admin`

Let's say "old uid" is 1000 and "new uid" is 2000, the command

`$ find /home -uid 1000 -exec chown 2000 {} \;` (probably you will need sudo)

will change the ownership of all files owned by "old-admin" recursively in `/home` to "new-admin".